# How can I install a locally developed WDM driver?

Tags: windows, windows-10, wdk, wdm

I'm following a video tutorial that covers developing WDM drivers and I've managed to put together a very barebones driver that doesn't really do anything other than print when it's loaded or unloaded. I did not make any modifications to the INF file generated by visual studio, and have built the driver successfully under Debug x64. Im slight confused by the output of the build, because the resulting driver and INF file are generated in two places:

1. Under *\ProjectName\x64\Debug* along with the pdb and certificate

[image: First driver / INF location]

2. Under *\ProjectName\x64\Debug\ProjectName* with only a cat file

[image: Second driver / INF location]

Attemnpting to install from teh first location gives me the error:

> The third-party INF does not contain digital signature information.

And from the second I get:

> A problem was encountered while attempting to add the driver to the store.

I've tried installing the certificate, but it doesn't seem to work and there's no information in the Event Log. I get this same error, attempting to install on my local machine and on a VM both running Win 10 x64.

I guess I have 2 question: for starters, why do two driver / INF pairs get generated, which is the right one for me to use? And secondly, what do I need to do / fix / change /etc. so that I can install my locally developed driver on my machine>

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/installing-an-unsigned-driver-during-development-and-test

Comment: you always need to install with.CAT file, go to c:\windows\inf\setupapi.dev.log and see which lines you have with !!!, this will tell you what is the error